# Convert all lowercase characters to uppercase and vice-versa

Tags: c, string

I am writing a C program to read characters one-by-one from standard input, convert all upper-case characters to lower-case and all lower-case characters to upper-case, and write the result to standard output.
I also want to count how many characters I have read, and how many of those  have converted in each direction, and output the totals at the end.

eg - Radha Krishna!
would become

rADHA kRISHNA!

Read 15 characters in total, 10 converted to upper-case, 2 to lower-case

Here's my code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    char sentence[100];
    int count, ch, i;

    printf("Enter a sentence \n");
    for (i = 0; (sentence[i] = getchar()) != '\n'; i++)
    {
        ;
    }
    sentence[i] = '\0';
    /*  shows the number of chars accepted in a sentence */
    count = i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        ch = islower(sentence[i])? toupper(sentence[i]) :
tolower(sentence[i]);
        putchar(ch);
    }
}
```

It is converting from uppercase to lowercase and vice-versa but i cant figure how to count.

Comment: Add two counters, set to 0, change ternary if operation to an if/else block, and increment one counter or the other. depending on "if" condition,

Comment: "*`for (i = 0; i < count; i++)`*" ???

Comment: Did you wrote this code shown?

Comment: What happens if the user enters ***more*** than `100` chars? You need to insure you do not write beyond the bounds of `sentence`. (perhaps add `i < 100 && ...`)

Answer (score 0):

Change the ternary to an if/else clause, and provide counters for each condition.

```
int changedToLower = 0;
int changedToUpper = 0;
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    char oldC = sentence[i];
    if(islower(sentence[i])) {
       ch = toupper(sentence[i])
       changeToUpper += (ch != oldC)? 1 : 0;
    } else {
       ch = tolower(sentence[i]);
       changeToLower += (ch != oldC)? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) This will count e.g. '!' and space as changed to lowered. There's three cases: lower, upper or neither. 2) `islower()` (`isupper()`) returning true doesn't neccessarily mean that the character can be changed with `toupper()` (`tolower()`); a locale could contain characters that have a lower (upper) case only.

Answer (score 0):

Let us review the contract first

1. a C program to read characters one-by-one from standard input,
2. convert all upper-case characters to lower-case and all lower-case characters to upper-case,
3. write the result to standard output.
4. ... count how many characters .. read,
5. ... how many of those have converted in each direction,
6. output the totals at the end.

Let us assume input characters can be *any* `char`, not just `A-Za-z`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    // No need to save previous letters
    // char sentence[100];
    unsigned long long character_count = 0; //#4
    unsigned long long toupper_count = 0;   //#5
    unsigned long long tolower_count = 0;   //#5

    printf("Enter a sentence\n");

    // for (i = 0; (sentence[i] = getchar()) != '\n'; i++)
    int ch;
    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {  // #1
      character_count++;               // #4
      if (ch == '\n') break;           // #1

      if (isupper(ch)) {
        ch = tolower(ch);       // #2
        tolower_count++;        // #5
      } else if (islower(ch)) { 
        ch = toupper(ch);       // #2
        toupper_count++;        // #5
      }

      putchar(ch);              // #3
    }

    printf("\n"                 // #6
        "Count: characters read   : %llu\n"
        "Count: converted to lower: %llu\n"
        "Count: converted to upper: %llu\n", 
        character_count, toupper_count, tolower_count);
}
```

Comment: Damn, must be a tough crowd tonight `:)`